# Match regex in any order

Tags: python, regex, match

I want to check for complex password with regular expression.

It should have 1 number 1 uppercase and one lowercase letter, not in specific order.
So i though about something like this:

```
m = re.search(r"([a-z])([A-Z])(\d)", "1Az")
print(m.group())
```

But i don't know how to tell him to search in any order.
I tried to look on web but I didn't found something interesting, thanks for help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could have tried looking for password validating regex, the site has a lot of them ;)

That said, you can use [positive lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to do that:

```
re.search(r"(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)", "1Az")
```

And to actually match the string...

```
re.search(r"(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{3}", "1Az")
```

And now, to ensure that the password is 3 chars long:

```
re.search(r"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{3}$", "1Az")
```

A positive lookahead `(?= ... )` makes sure the expression inside is present in the string to be tested. So, the string has to have a lowercase character (`(?=.*[a-z])`), an uppercase character (`(?=.*[A-Z])`) and a digit (`(?=.*\d)`) for the regex to 'pass'.

Comment: i really new with regex concept, what "?=." mean? that meby there is something before him?

Comment: @OrHalimi I provided a link and an explanation in my answer. It's not `?=.`, it's `(?= )` and `.*`. The first is a lookahead, the second means any character (except newlines) any number of times. This allows to 'search' anywhere in the string to make sure that there's the pattern ahead. So, if you have `(?=.*a)`, it will make sure that there's an `a` anywhere in the string you're testing it against.

Comment: ok thank, regular expression is one of the hard things to understand. I will look at the link you gave me. Thanks alot

Comment: @OrHalimi Yes, it can be hard to understand at first, unfortunately ^^

Comment: Note that: `(?=.*[a-z])` can be more efficiently written as: `(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])`. This same technique can be applied to the other lookaheads as well.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just:

```
if (re.search(r"[a-z]", input) and re.search(r"[A-Z]", input) and re.search(r"[0-9]", input)):
    # pass
else
    # don't pass
```

Comment: Wow.. what's with that logic? No need for the `== None`... and just `and` them...

Comment: +1 Yep, that's the usually preferred alternative; to test each separately. Though might need to optimize it a bit more.

Comment: @JonClements Sorry I don't work with Python, if you could edit the answer I would be grateful.

Comment: well this is an easy way. but what if i had 10 different expression? i want to find short solution. :-)

Comment: @OrHalimi Jerry's solution or mine are the two alternatives you can use, if you could find better ones then please let me know.

Comment: @Jerry solution look interesting, but i don't understand it yet. Thanks anyway,

Comment: @OrHalimi The main thing you need to understand about Jerry's solution is that look ahead doesn't consume any character from the input string when it tries to match something, and if any single one of them fails then the whole expression fails immediately.

Comment: `all(re.search(pattern, text) for pattern in ('[A-Z]', '[a-z]', r'\d'))` would make this even simpler...

Comment: @JonClements Beautiful solution, I wanted to continue learning Python but I don't have the time, it's a shame :)