# how to use variables in Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a function that checks for a strong password. The password must contain one upper case, one lower case,a number and must be 8 characters long.

```
import re

def checker():

 while True:
   userInput = input(' Please input a password ')
   passwordRegex = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+ {,8}')
   match = passwordRegex.search(userInput)
   if match:
        print('Good!')
   else:
        print('Bad!')

checker()
```

This function always outputs `Bad` even when the password meets all the requirements. I have a feeling the error has to do with how I am using my Regex and Variables. I am using python 3.6.

Comment: This has nothing to do with variables. It's just that 1) your regex is wrong and 2) you're using the regex wrong (`re.search`).

Comment: https://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: note that you regex tries to match literally ` {,8}`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @Aran-Fey, I have update my code based on your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the feedback from  @Aran-Fey and @Tomerikoo, i have updated my code and it works now.

```py
import re

def checker():

    while True:

    userInput = input(' Please input a password ')

    passwordRegex = re.search(r'^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$',userInput)

    if passwordRegex:

        break

     print('Good!')


checker()
```

Comment: This will only look for at least one letter and at least one number. Meaning this password `tomerkal9` will pass. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: I am following a python book(automate the boring stuff with python) and yes this satisfies the requirement for the exercise. Appreciate the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944909/match-regex-in-any-order):

```py
passwordRegex = re.compile("^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])\S{8,}")
```

check out [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/xMIzwh/1)

Using lookaheads we make sure there is at least one character from each group, then require at least 8 characters total. Note that you can customize the allowed characters (if you want to allow symbols) by changing the last group, the one before `{8,}`