# Guess a 3 letter string that contains an uppercase, lowercase and number (in any order)

Tags: python, string, for-loop, cracking

I'm relatively new with Python and I'm making a program where we recieve a 3 letter long string with one upper case letter, one lower case letter and a number in any given order. The program is then supposed to find it through a brute-force attack.

I've tried doing this through for loops and defining the uppercase, lowercase letters and letters as strings and then try to iterate through these with for loops and try to match the letters from the string we wanted to find to those within the uppercase, lowercase or numbers accordingly.

What I tried to do:

```
uppers="ABCDEFGHIJ"
lowers="abcdefghij"
numbers="1234567890"
secret="Je1" #The string the computer is supposed to find through a brute-force attack 

password = ""
counter = 0

for upper in uppers:
    if upper in secret:
        password += upper
        break
    else:
        counter += 1

for lower in lowers:
    if lower in secret:
        password += lower
        break
    else:
        counter += 1

for number in numbers:
    if number in secret:
        password += number
        break
    else:
        counter += 1

print(password)
print("Counter: {0}".format(counter))
```

When I run the code, it does work, but only when the *secret* string is in a different order than uppercase, lowercase and numbers,("Je1" works, "eJ1" doesn't). The program doesn't really do its function properly without rearranging the for loops accordingly.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944909/match-regex-in-any-order

Comment: Your approach simply relies on the numbers being in that order, as you found out yourself. You'll have to adjust that accordingly. As a suggestion and not to spoil your homework, try to describe the algorithm to a human first and see if that gives the correct results. Also, very helpful, step through the code in a debugger in order to find out the place where the program is not behaving as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code very specifically always outputs uppercase, lowercase, and number in exactly this order, regardless of what the input was.

This is possible to fix in several ways, each with some tradeoffs.

The simplest is to really do brute force, i.e. examine all three sets at every position.

As an optimization, you could drop the category you found a match in from subsequent iterations, reducing the search space as you go. This is unlikely to be scalable to real-world problems, where the search space is more complex (you don't know if there will be one or more occurrences of characters in any one category, except if one category is not yet attested for near the end of the string).

Alternatively, you could remember at which position you found a character in a particular category, and reassemble the password in the right order at the end with this information. In some sense, this is the most elegant fix, but again, it suffers from the problem that it's not going to be very useful in a real-world password cracking program.

So in other words, the "full brute force" solution is the most scalable, because it will scale up to real-world problems, even though it is computationally the least scalable.

Going forward, think about how you could enumerate all possible passwords in the search space, so that each password candidate gets a predictable index, and just loop over that enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to accomplish this in Python is using [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations). This gives you all possible combinations from a given collection of items.

In your case the "collection of items" are all the lower-case letters, upper-case letters and numbers. So to use `permutations` you need to put them together into one collection. For this you can just concatenate the strings together:

```
chars = uppers + lowers + numbers
```

Or simply define them as one string:

```
chars = "ABCDEFGHIJabcdefghij1234567890"
```

You can then run `permutations(chars, 3)` which gives you items of 3 characters in length as a tuple. One example would be `('a', 'C', '3')`. You need to compare this with the password-string. You can either split the password string into a tuple (which needs to be done once), or join the permutation tuple into a string (which needs to be done for each item). In your case, I am assuming that you want to use the generated password for something, so let's join the tuple into a string, which gives us the following code:

```
from itertools import permutations

uppers="ABCDEFGHIJ"
lowers="abcdefghij"
numbers="1234567890"

secret="Je1"

for candidate in permutations(uppers + lowers + numbers, 3):
    if ''.join(candidate) == secret:
        print(candidate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following program is slightly inefficient but works for your purpose.

```
import re
def m(secret):
    import re
    if len(secret)==3 and re.search(r'[A-Z]', secret) and re.search(r'[a-z]', secret) and re.search(r'[0-9]', secret):
        print "Yes"
    else:
        print "No"
```

Which can be further modified using `positive lookaheads` as mentioned in the accepted answer of [Match regex in any order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944909/match-regex-in-any-order-)

```
if re.search(r"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{3}$", secret):
    print "Yes"
else:
    print "No"
```

Comment: This doesn't perform a brute-force guessing attack, it just verifies that the string meets the criteria. (To be honest I thought that was the question at first, too; hopefully it's clearer now.)

Answer (score 0):

You're looping in the order upper, lower, number, so you can only match strings that are in that specific order. You need to loop in all possible permutations of upper, lower, number. That is, you need to repeat what you did for these permutations:

upper, number, lower
lower, upper, number
lower, number, upper
number, lower, upper
number, upper, lower

You can shorten your three loops this way:

```
for upper in uppers:
    for lower in lowers:
        for number in numbers:
            password = upper + lower + number
            if password == secret:
                print('Matched. Secret is', secret)
```

Repeat this five more times by changing the order of upper, lower, number.

Or, you can use `itertools` package to avoid having to loop so many times.

```
from itertools import permutations

for upper in uppers:
    for lower in lowers:
        for number in numbers:
            perms = list(permutations([upper, lower, number]))
            if tuple(secret) in perms:
                print('Matched. Secret is', secret)
```